# Make a copy button for a cell in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm stuck with a problem on google sheet, I know the solution is apps script but I have limited knowledge in this area, I would like to create a button that copy a cell, that's all, someone can help me?

Comment: Please describe your workflow more closely. What the cell? Where copy to? Screenshots, a link to the sheet maybe. Etc.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

#### Get Current Cell Value

```
function copyCurrentCell() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getCurrentCell().getValue();
}

function launchSidebar() {
  let ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<input type="text" id="txt1" /><br /><input type="button" value="Get Current Cell Value" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler( (v) => {document.getElementById(\'${"txt1"}\').value = v;}).copyCurrentCell();" />`);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui)
}
```